# Add attributes from object key:value pairs in Jade

Tags: javascript, pug

Given an array of objects with unknown key-value pairs:

```
meta: [
  { name: 'description', content: 'some description' },
  { name: 'keywords', content: 'some keywords' }
]
```

Using [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) I would like to output:

```
<meta name="description" content="some description" />
<meta name="keyword" content="some keywords" />
```

The attributes could be other things so it's important that it is dynamic.

Never used Jade before but the rough idea is something like

```
each m in meta
  meta(
    each val, key in m ..print them
  )
```

Obviously not valid and not sure of how to go about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The answer was impressively simple using the [and attribute](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/#and-attributes):

```
each m in meta
  meta()&attributes(m)
```